# Dynamically convert a string to a variable name in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, rename

I would like to convert a string to a variable name to create a reusable function.

Here I have created a small JSBin to illustrate: http://jsbin.com/hamuzawe/1/edit

In the JSbin there are country data and each country is assigned a Color Bin (BIN_1to19 or BIN_20to49) and is then visualised in the according colour on the world map.

What I'd like to be able to do is the following. The reusable function has always the colour bins:

```
  BIN_1: 'darkblueblue',
  BIN_2: 'darkred'
```

But these colour bins are interpreted differently – according to the chosen bin width. So one time it is read by Javascript as

```
  BIN_1to19: 'darkblue',
  BIN_20to49: 'darkred'
```

And another time as

```
  BIN_1to59: 'darkblue',
  BIN_60to129: 'darkred'
```

Is that possible?

In other answers to similar questions I read that

```
BIN_1 = "BIN_1to19",
BIN_2 = "BIN_20to49"
```

and then

```
window["BIN_1"]: 'darkblue
window["BIN_2"]: 'darkred',
```

should do what I want but it does not..

Could someone help me?
Thank you!!

Comment: `window["BIN_1"] = 'darkblue'` should set it globally.

Comment: you could also just use a named array

Comment: as BIN_1 is a variable you need to use it as `window[BIN_1]` without the quotes around BIN_1

Comment: Thank you! But I cannot just call it BIN_1 etc cause then it doesn't work with the legend.. For the legend to work the variables really have to be "1 to 19", "20 to 39"

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, isn't BIN_1 referring to the string "BIN_1to19"?

Comment: It should dynamically be replaced by it. Where there is the variable BIN_1 now there should be a command that puts the string "BIN_1to19" or really just "1 to 19" there so that the variable is called "1 to 19" and never BIN_1. Maybe that is just not possible?

Comment: Your approach is wrong, I can see what you are doing from the jsbin you posted but the way to accomplish this is not by setting a bunch of global JS variables.  To me it looks like you want to change the shading color used by each country based on certain criteria which presumably you have stored somewhere.

Comment: Yes! This is what I want to do. (But there is also the condition that it has to have a meaningful name – because it is used for the legend.)

Comment: Take a look at [this edit](http://jsbin.com/hamuzawe/4/edit)